# Replace Win10's Powershell with Powershell 6.0.0

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

The question is simple, even though the answer might not be, but how can I replace Windows 10 default powershell (major 5) with the one on GitHub (Major 6)?

If installed normally it'll be installed in `%programfiles%\PowerShell` with executable named `pwsh.exe`. Is there a way of updating PS 'locally' so that it gets automatically replaced by the newest one? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[PowerShell Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/01/10/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/) intentionally does *not* replace the built-in PowerShell:

> ## Does PowerShell Core affect my Windows PowerShell installation?
>
> Nope! PowerShell Core is completely side-by-side with Windows PowerShell. In fact, an awesome feature of PowerShell Core is that you can test new versions without affecting existing workloads. Whether it’s installed via an MSI or installed portably from the ZIP package, your Windows PowerShell installation is not affected by PowerShell Core.

Since [PS Core *does* have backwards-compatibility-breaking changes](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4062), this is probably not a good idea just yet. You'll find some administrative modules will not work in PowerShell Core.

[Microsoft is still working on a roadmap for bundling PowerShell Core into Windows by default.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/PowerShell-AMA/Will-powershell-core-become-default/td-p/143824) It is entirely possible that the older PowerShell 5.1 is still included for backwards compatibility - in much the same way IE is still included despite Edge being the default.

---

If your goal is just that launching `powershell.exe` will launch Core, you can place the PS Core folder earlier in the `PATH` so it is discovered first. Note that this *could* break scripts that need anything PS Core does not support.

Comment: Is it possible to at least update the PowerShell revision?

Comment: @VictorMarcelino At the moment it's looking likely that 5.1 will be the last version of "Desktop" (i.e. non-Core) PowerShell. You're probably best off just waiting until Core it's properly natively bundled. Keep in mind that 5.1 is still the latest supported version - at the moment, 6 does not replace 5; 6 is a **different product**.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear, sorry. I was referring to the revision and build number. At the moment I have in one of my PCs the following Major:5; Minor:1; Build:16299; Revision:98 whereas on the other one I have Major:5; Minor:1; Build:15063; Revision:786. It seems weird to me that they are different (but still version 5.1) so I imagine that one of them is outdated and I could not find a way to update

Comment: @VictorMarcelino Ah, that. It seems to be tied to the Windows version (16299 is Windows 10 1709 while 15063 is Windows 10 1703). Traditionally, you'd install a newer WMF package - but it looks like that's no longer the case as of Windows 10. Perhaps you could manually copy files from a newer Win10 install, but that would likely cause more problems than it would solve. In any case, there wouldn't be any significant changes to PowerShell itself. Your best bet (on Windows 10) is to let the OS manage the PowerShell version for you and just keep the OS up to date. (on 7 and 8, install newer WMF)

Comment: For reference, the current PowerShell shipped in WMF 5.1 for Windows 7 is 5.1.14409.1005.

Comment: The `PATH` trick does not work as version 6.2.3 does not include any binary called `powershell.exe`.

Comment: More info on their future replacement plans:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/the-next-release-of-powershell-powershell-7/